# Running php behat.phar but using only behat short name how?

Tags: behat

I can run behat by

```
php behat.phar
```

How can I run(like in the manual) by using only

```
behat
```

I suppose I can

```
chmod +x behat.phar
mv behat.phar /usr/local/bin/behat
```

No go.

I suppose I can

```
ln -s /wherebehatis/behar.phar /usr/local/bin/behat
```

No go either.

So what can I do?

Comment: mv + chmod works for me. Is your PHP in the PATH? Is the /usr/local/bin in the PATH?

Comment: Actually, I have 2 version php on the server. But if I use just "php". It is the one if I use /usr/local/php/bin/php full path, telling from "php --version". What should I do to make bahat use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/php/bin/php /wherebehatis/behar.phar "$@"
```

give the script "behat" name and put it in a folder into the PATH, like /usr/local/sbin